# \iftoggle inside theorem

Tags: errors, theorems

I have

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sol}
\toggletrue{sol}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Text
    \iftoggle{sol}{Text}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting and error sayin that \begin{theorem} was ended by \end{document}.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's really hard to trouble shoot an error if you are not given enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: @Andrew: Done ...

Comment: If should be `\iftoggle{sol}{true code}{false code}`. As you haven't given the false code the `\end{theorem}` is being eaten up and used as this instead, causing your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\iftoggle` expects three arguments. One for the toggle, one for the true-branch and one for false. You should use it like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sol}
\toggletrue{sol}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Text
    \iftoggle{sol}{Text}{}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Without the additional `{}` `\end` gets eaten by `\iftoggle`.